Is 11/32 plywood too thin for shed roof sheathing?
I purchased and already am halfway through installing 11/32 plywood sheathing on my shed roof. I have 2x4 purlins running over top of the rafters for added strength. I just read that thicker sheathing would have been more ideal, but wondering if I will be ok finishing up with the 11/32 or whether I should add a second layer?

3/8" (11/32) plywood is code minimum for roof sheathing. If your framing that it rests on is 16" centers, it will be fine, especially for a shed.
Depending on your roofing material, you may want to add more, for example, if it is regular shingles, and nailed or stapled down, fine. If it will be a metal roof and screwed down, you will want a thicker material.
